# Should these related C and C++ questions be marked as duplicates?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow, duplicate-questions

There are a whole bunch of questions about whether you can declare multiple variables of different types in a for-loop initializer:

- C

  - <del>[Two variables in a 'for' loop in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7783284/two-variables-in-a-for-loop-in-c)</del>  <sub>Not a dupe, misread the question</sub>
  - [How to initialize several variables in a for (;;) loop in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348766/how-to-initialize-several-variables-in-a-for-loop-in-c)
  - [Is for ({statements;}; condition; {statements;}) legal C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852019/is-for-statements-condition-statements-legal-c) (closely related)
- C++

  - [Is there a way to define variables of two different types in a for loop initializer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866012/is-there-a-way-to-define-variables-of-two-different-types-in-a-for-loop-initiali)
  - [In C++ why can't I write a for() loop like this: for( int i = 1, double i2 = 0;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337126/in-c-why-cant-i-write-a-for-loop-like-this-for-int-i-1-double-i2-0)
  - [Multiple Counter Problem In For Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340073/multiple-counter-problem-in-for-loop)
  - [How to declare a second iterator inside a for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8728524/how-to-declare-a-second-iterator-inside-a-for-loop)
  - [Is it possible to declare two variables of different types in a for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687392/is-it-possible-to-declare-two-variables-of-different-types-in-a-for-loop)
  - [New ISO scoping rule for " for LOOP"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11329313/new-iso-scoping-rule-for-for-loop)
  - [Can I declare variables of different types in the initialization of a for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644707/can-i-declare-variables-of-different-types-in-the-initialization-of-a-for-loop)
  - [Error in iterator declaration in a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407713/error-in-iterator-declaration-in-a-for-loop)
  - [Commas in for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3383968/commas-in-for-loop) (very similar but not identical since variables are of same type)

Clearly the C questions (resp. C++ questions) should be duped together.

Now C and C++ are quite distinct languages. However, in this case, the questions are all asking about a feature of C (technically C99) syntax that (I think) was taken unchanged into C++. Here, any answer to the C question will equally apply to the C++ one. So should these be duped into a single question for both C and C++ here?

Related: [Should we close VB.NET questions as duplicates of C# questions and likewise?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94121/should-we-close-vb-net-questions-as-duplicates-of-c-questions-and-likewise) 's accepted answer is that a question about .NET framework features common to 2 languages warrant closing as a duplicate.

Comment: Check carefully that the feature are the same between the 2 languages, and whether the thing being asked in the question doesn't depend on a difference between 2 languages. There are some small difference between the 2 language that makes the answer right or wrong (particularly UB for certain expression `i = i++`).

Comment: @nhahtdh: In general that's true, but I don't think C++ extends the syntax for variable declarations in this case.

Comment: You are probably right. I haven't checked the standard, but it is likely that there is no difference here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Questions must not be marked as duplicates if they would have different answer. C and C++ may have the same feature now, but a good C answer would point out compatibility issues with older compilers, and a good C++ answer would point out *different* compatibility issues with older compilers.

Furthermore, while the C questions are about related topics, none of the three is a duplicate of any other. I won't venture to judge the C++ questions but they don't all look like duplicates of each other either.

Answer (score 0):

There are some criteria for me:

1. Are they the same language or nearly the same? (`for` in C and C++ declarations are the same if for example, don't use `std::safe_pointer`)
2. Do they cover the same area? (Your first two both covered `for` loops, but the problem was in different areas of it)

Comment: Right. The first one has problem in the condition part. The others are mostly about the initialization part.

Comment: That's my mistake; the very first one isn't a duplicate. Edited (and added some more dupes)